# Melhor forma de adicionar muito HTML na página via JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Galera, estou criando uma pequena rede social (one page) e queria saber qual a melhor forma de adicionar muito html á página. Vou explicar melhor: eu tenho uma `div` chamada timeline que serve como container e dentro dela em tese é para ser adicionado outra `div`, os feeds de notícias e publicações; só que essa `div` é muito grande e um pouco complexa para concatenada em uma variável js e eventualmente usar alguma função para adiciona-lá. Será que há uma melhor forma de se fazer esse processo?

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap_ui" id="timeline">
            <div class="timeline_feed">
            <div class="feed_row">
                <div class="feed_info">
                    <img src="public/img/no_photo.png">
                </div>
                <div class="feed_info" style="font-weight: bold; color: #666;">
                    No name
                </div>
                <div class="feed_info">
                    "No status"
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="feed_row">
                <article>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure...
                </article>
            </div>
            <div class="feed_row" style="border-top: 1px solid #eee;">
                <div class="feed_opt">
                    <img src="public/img/icones/love-icon-hover.png">
                </div>
                <div class="feed_opt">
                    3k
                </div>
                <div class="feed_opt">
                    <img src="public/img/icones/share-icon.png">
                </div>
                <div class="feed_opt">
                    4k
                </div>
                <div class="feed_opt">
                    <img src="public/img/icones/comment-icon.png">
                </div>
                <div class="feed_opt">
                    34k
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.timeline_feed{
    width: inherit;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    /*...*/
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;*/
}

.feed_row{
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;

    /*...*/
    background-color: inherit;
}

.feed_row > .feed_info{
    display: inline-block;


    /*...*/

}

.feed_row > .feed_info:first-child{ margin-right: 10px; }
.feed_row > .feed_info:last-child{ margin-left: 50px;   }


.feed_row > .feed_info > img{
    width: 4.3em;
    height: 4.3em;
    vertical-align: middle;

    /*...*/
    border-radius: 50%;

}

.feed_row > .feed_info > .feed_name_user{
    font-weight: 700;

    /*...*/
    color: #444;
}

.feed_row > .feed_info > .feed_status_user{
    color: #666;
}

.feed_row > article{
    padding: 20px 5px;
    word-spacing: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    /*...*/
    color: #555;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.feed_row > .feed_opt{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 7px;

    /*...*/
    color: #666;

}

.feed_row > .feed_opt > img{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, acho que no seu caso o melhor é usar um framework do tipo o Angular.JS https://angularjs.org/ tem bastante material na net sobre isso.

abrs

Comment: Dando uma olhada bem por cima aqui no AngularJS ele me pareceu a alternativa mais viável para solução do meu problema. Abs